# $ord_{n}(k) = \infty$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, multiplicative-order

For example:

$14^{0} \pmod 2 = 1$

$14^{1} \pmod 2 = 0$

$14^{2} \pmod 2 = 0$

...

They will never be achieved again number one. So $ord_{2}(14) = \infty$?

When $ord_{n}(k) = \infty$?

Comment: The order of $a \pmod n$ only makes sense when $\gcd (a,n)=1$, for the reason you cite.

Comment: See definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order

Comment: "When $ord_{n}(k) = \infty$?" is not a inquisition.