# multiplicative order $ord_{a }(k)$ if $gcd (a, k) > 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, multiplicative-order

The question concerns the multiplicative order $ord_{a}(k)$ if $gcd (a, k) > 1$.

$2^{0} \pmod 4 = 1$

$2^{1} \pmod 4 = 0$

$2^{2} \pmod 4 = 0$

$2^{3} \pmod 4 = 0$

$2^{4} \pmod 4 = 0$

...

$4^{0} \pmod 6 = 1$

$4^{1} \pmod 6 = 4$

$4^{2} \pmod 6 = 4$

$4^{3} \pmod 6 = 4$

$4^{4} \pmod 6 = 4$

...

Is there always an $x$ such that $k^{x} \pmod a = k^{x+1} \pmod a$?

What is the maximum value (minimum correct $x$) of which can take $x$ for defined data $a$ and $k$?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872704/ord-nk-infty).

Comment: How do you come up with $4^{1} \pmod 6 = 2$?

Comment: @T. Bongers: Ah ok. And there was a formula for the maximum length of the pattern? In the example given you length is 2.

Comment: @Zack Ni: Sorry my mistake.

Comment: @MarekWolny The length of the pattern corresponds to finding $\ell$ for which $a | k^x (k^{\ell} - 1)$. I suppose that by reducing $a$ and $k$ by the gcd, you can reduce this into computing the order of something related to $k$ in a different modulus.

Comment: @T. Bongers: The length of the pattern in this case (gcd > 1) always divides the Carmichael function λ(k) analogous to $ord_{k}(n)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ exists so that

$$k^x \equiv k^{x + 1} \pmod{a}$$

then we have

$$a | k^x (k - 1)$$

---

This motivates the counterexample $a = 6, k = 2$ for the first question.